# random.randint function isnt working the way i would like it to

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Whenever I run this program (not a serious program just messing around getting an idea of things) the damage from the `monster (monster[1])` just repeats the same number over and over again. It randomizes once then just repeats it. I understand WHATS happening but I don't understand WHY it is. Here is the code (I'm sorry I don't know if I'm making my question clear or not...makes sense in my head lol)

EDIT - I would like the monster[1] function to randomize each time but I don't know how to do it without writing more code (i.e `damage=random.randint(5, 15)` `health-=damage`). If I write it like that it works fine. But I dont want to write that specially if I have a series of 10 different monsters. I would like to just call upon each monster and have it run by itself if that makes sense.

EDIT#2: Is it possible to create a tuple within a list since tuples are immutable (i.e `monster=[100, (random.randint(5, 15)), random.randint(15, 30)]` this code doesn't work I've tried it already but just wondering if it would be possible.

```
import random
monster = [100, random.randint(5, 15), random.randint(15, 30)]
health = 200
a = 1

print "you run into a monster"
while a == 1:
    if monster[0] <= 0:
        print "monster is dead"
        print "you get, " + str(monster[1]) + " exp"
        a += 1
    elif monster[0] >= 0:
        att = random.randint(5, 15)
        monster[0] -= att
        health -= monster[1]
        print ("you attack the monster and do, " + str(att) + " damage"
               " the monster does," + str(monster[1]) + " damage to you")
        print "you have, " + str(health) + " health left"
        print "monster has, " + str(monster[0]) + " health left"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monster[1]` get assigned a random integer on the second line of your code. It then is stored in the list `monster` as an integer. That integer is going to remain the same. You would have to rerun the `random.randint(5, 15)` call to get a new "damage" number or new exp amount.

Though I think it may be beyond the scope of what you are working on here, you may want to look into creating a `class` monster instead of using an array, and then having a method that generates these random integers each time it attacks.

Here is an example monster class that may give you the idea of how it works.

```
class monster():
    def __init__(self,health):
        self.health = health

    def attack(self):
        return random.randint(5,15)
```

You can then create a new monster as follows.

```
monster = monster(100)
```

See how much damage it does as follows.

```
monsterDamage = monster.attack()
health -= monsterDamage
print "The monster does " + str(monsterDamage) + " damage to you."
```

And lower the monster's health as follows.

```
att = random.randint(5,15)
monster.health -= att
```

Comment: @DHandle-im still learning python I havent learnt classes yet.

Comment: @user2423223 Understandable! Feel free to ask more questions and you might reference this, http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html, if you wanted to learn more.

Comment: thank you for the ref material. Im learning from a book and some stuff they dont really go much into detail with it

Comment: the python.org website really is a great reference. Easy to read and presents everything fairly simply with additional reading and examples to "get down deeper" when you want to know more.

Comment: @user2423223 I added some example class code to maybe help you get started.

Comment: @DHandle- thank you. man programming just seems to get more and more confusing

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
monster=[100,random.randint(5, 15), random.randint(15, 30)]
```

saves `100` and two random numbers *once*. For example, this may be the representation of `monster` at runtime:

```
monster=[100, 11, 26]
```

And these numbers don't change, because the assignment happens *only once*. (eg. outside the loop)

Answer (score 1):

`monster=[100,random.randint(5, 15), random.randint(15, 30)]`

When you define this list, it will be the same throughout. The values will not change every time you do `monster[1]`.

To fix this, you could do something like:

```
monster=[100, random.randint, random.randint]
```

And when you go to call it:

```
monster[1](15, 15)
```

Just an option. Although a dictionary could be better here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you gave `monster[1]` a value only once, in the 2nd line:

```
monster=[100,random.randint(5, 15), random.randint(15, 30)]
```

That line is executed only once, so "of course" `monster[1]` is always the same.  If you want `monster[1]` (and/or `monster[2]` too) to change, you need to give it a new value **inside** your loop.  You did that for `att`!  You need to do something similar for all the other things you want to see change :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you call your line:

```
monster = [100, random.randint(5, 15), ...]
```

the function random.randint(5, 15) is executed and a specific value is stored in the list.

I'm going to present one more alternative to do what you want, through the storage of the function as a string; you can write:

```
monster = [100, "random.randint(5, 15)", ...]
```

then when you want to get a new random integer you call:

```
r=eval(monster[1])
```

and that gives you a different integer each time you call it, because the function is re-evaluated.

(notice that if you want to re-use a random value, for instance to print it, you must store it in a temporary variable, "r", and then use str(r), instead of str(eval(monster[1])), as the former way prints the result of the call stored in "r", and the later way re-evaluates again the function).

eg.

```
    tmp = eval(monster[1])
    health -= tmp
    print ("you attack the monster and do, " + str(att) + " damage. the monster does," + str(tmp) + " damage to you")
```